# What can be the value of $m$ in following equation

Tags: recreational-mathematics

During calculations I got this step
$$(e^m/((m+1)^{m+1}) )^{3n/4} = 1/2^n$$

I want the value of m here??

Comment: Assuming $n,m\in\Bbb R$ (or some subset), take the $\frac {3n}4$ root of both sides, then see what else makes sense from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can eliminate $n$ by raising both sides to $4/(3n)$:

$$\frac{e^m}{(m+1)^{m+1}} = \frac{1}{2^{4/3}}.$$

I don't think there's much hope of a closed-form solution, but Wolfram Alpha can easily find $m$ [numerically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=E%5Em%20==%202%5E%28-4/3%29%20%28m%2b1%29%5E%28m%2b1%29&a=%2aC.m-_%2aVariable.dflt-&a=%5E_Real).

Note that more, (likely complex, depending on $n$) solutions also exist -- multiply the right-hand side by $4/(3n)$th roots of unity.